# Why XGB model is not giving output on validation dataset but work better for training

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, logistic-regression, xgboost

Currently i am working on a project whose objective is to find the customer who has more probability to purchase your project.Its a classification model (0 & 1 ).
I have created model with RF and XGB both & calculated gain score ( Data is imbalanced ).Not my more than 80 % customers covering in top 3 decile for training data but when i run the model on validation dataset, it fall back to 56-59 % in both model.

Say i have 20 customers & for better accuracy , i have clustered them, Now model is giving perfect result on cluster 1 customers but perform poor on cluster 2 customers.

Any suggestion to tune the same.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if there is a high accuracy difference between your training and validation set your model may suffer from bias. You may need to use a more complex model for this training.

Secondly, because of the imbalance of your dataset, you maybe want to resample the training set. You can use under-sampling or over-sampling techniques(`SMOTE`).

Thirdly, you may need to use the right evaluation metrics like precision, recall, F1.

Finally, in train/val/test split you need to be careful about the distribution of your dataset. So you can use the `stratified` keyword to handle this problem.

Comment: I have used GLM/ RF & XGB with parameter tuned. What other model would help ? & i can not use smote because almost all variable are categorical & smote won't apply on categorical variables(i think so ) and for accuracy metric, our motive is to find the more positive response ( sensitivity ) but as data is imbalanced & we can't apply smote so we are using gain score to get maximum customer in top 3 decile.

Comment: You can use Gridsearch for tuning your parameters and also try other classification algorithms like logistic regression, SVM or Neural Networks. Also if you have enough data to handle the imbalance dataset problem you can also make downsampling the majority class.